# Rendering two componets in router-outlet while navigating using navigatebyUrl in angular

Tags: angular, routes

## My requirement and setUp

I have mat-tab in which there are two tabs --> Tab 1, Tab 2.
Tab 2 has the search operation. So I have a mat-table, in that one column has a link. upon clicking that link it should navigate to tab1 and display respective information.

The issue here is both Tab 2 and Tab 1 are getting displayed.

```
<app-dashboard-page></app-dashboard-page>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start">
   <mat-tab label="First">Tab 1</mat-tab>
   <mat-tab label="Second">Tab 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

In Tab 2 I have something like below.
[image]

When I click on GetInfo link it should navigate to Tab 1 and display records.
But both components are loading on same page .

```
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Run ID </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                <a [routerLink]="[]" (click)="getByRunId(row.runId)">
                  {{ row.runId }}
                </a>
              </mat-cell>

    getByRunId(runId: any) {
this.zone.run(() => {
this.router.navigate(['/getQualifiedBalanceByJobId'], {
state: { data: { runId: runId } },
});
});
}
     <mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start">
   <mat-tab label="First">Tab 1</mat-tab>
   <mat-tab label="Second">Tab 2</mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>

{path: 'getQualifiedBalanceByJobId', component: DashboardPageComponent}
```

Comment: Can you show your router config, and the HTML of `Get info` ?

Comment: @Random Here is my htl and router config


<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <a [routerLink]="[]" (click)="getByRunId(row.runId)">
              {{ row.runId }}
            </a>
          </mat-cell>

Comment: @Random





Method on click router-link
===============================

  getByRunId(runId: any) {
    //this.openBalanceMovementByRunId(runId);
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/getQualifiedBalanceByJobId'], {
        state: { data: { runId: runId } },
      });
    });
  }

Comment: @Random
{path: 'getQualifiedBalanceByJobId', component: DashboardPageComponent}

Comment: please add it to your question, not in comment, so you can format it ^^

Comment: @Random I have added it to Question.

Comment: 2 odd things I see: You have to choose between `[routerLink]` and `(click) ` in the HTML. No need for `this.zone.run()`. If code is that simple, you may be able to do what you wish with `[routerLink]` and `[routerLinkOptions]`. Also, why do you use `data` istead of simple query params ? You could do something like `{path: 'getQualifiedBalanceByJobId/:id', component: DashboardPageComponent}`